# Real time RSSI from Clients

Tags: cisco, wireless, snmp, access-point, wlc

I have a Cisco WLC and different LWAPPs. What I am looking for is a way to be able to get in the WLC the RSSI of all connected clients.

For the moment, I am able to access through SNMP to the *AIRESPACE-WIRELESS-MIB* on the WLC. There, I can access the *bsnMobileStationRssiDataTable*, where all the connected clients have an entry, indexed by each LWAPPs. The main problem is that the RSSI update is really slow, like every 3 to 5 minutes.

What I am looking for is for a refresh rate of at least 5 to 10 seconds.

Is there any way of doing this, or is there another MIB where this information can be retrieve?

I am really struggling to get this information through the Cisco forums/websites.

Comment: Here’s an interesting article on [Why RSSI isn't very useful for signal measurements.](http://tomatousb.org/tut:measuring-rssi-with-wifi-cards).  “You see the problem with trying to make meaningful conclusions with what amounts to a total pile of crap as a basis?”

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the RSSI of connected clients, you will need this OID:

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.273.1.3.1.1.3
```

In regards to graphing the information every 5 or 10 seconds, you could use monitoring software like Cacti to achieve this.

References:

- [Cacti Forum](http://forums.cacti.net/about4901.html) - Client Table RSSI value for your clients.
- [Cisco Forum](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10196106/snmp-monitoring) - Signal Strength (dBm)
- [ipswitch](http://docs.ipswitch.com/NM/85_WhatsUp%20Gold%20v14.2/03_Help/index.htm?Wireless_active_clients.htm?zoom_highlight=wireless?toc.htm) - Signal Strength
- [Cisco OID Navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.273.1.3.1.1.3) - RSSI Indicator.

Comment: What @OzNetNerd didn't explicitly say is that you will have to get this info directly from the APs, not from the controller.

Comment: The problem is that my AP are configure as LWAPs, so i need to do all the snmp poll through the WLC, isn't it ? And I tried to access the OID cDot11ClientSignalStrength in the WLC with no luck.

Comment: There is a way to get this info using the command line directly into the WLC or the AP ?